# Ошибка c PictureBox в UserControl

Tags: c#

Использую UserControl, который содержит PictureBox. При добавлении UserControl на форму появляется ошибка представленная на картинке.При этом изображение на PictureBox рисуется правильно т.е. как бы все работает как нужно. Но ошибка не исчезает. **В чем может быть причина ошибки?**
[image]

**Код формы:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(int nn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        y = new double[nn];
        n = nn;
        x = new double[nn];
    }
    public int n;
    public double[] y;
    public double f_d;
    double[] x;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl11.Length = n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            userControl11.x[i] = i / f_d;
            userControl11.y[i] = y[i];
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
    private void userControl11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}     
}
```

**Код UserControl:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double x_max, x_min, y_max, y_min, x_0_pix, y_0_pix, y_1, x_1_pix, y_1_pix;
    public double[]  x, y;
    int length;

    public int Length
    {
        set
        {
            length = value;
            y = new double[length];
            x = new double[length];
        }
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int xform = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int width = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
        int height = pictureBox1.Size.Height;

        int i;
        double k, d;

        y_max = y_min = y[0];
        x_min = x[0];

        for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (y[i] > y_max) y_max = y[i];
            if (y[i] < y_min) y_min = y[i];

            x_max = x[i];
        }

        d = width / (x_max - x_min);
        k = -height / (y_max - y_min);
        y_0_pix = k * (y[0] - y_min) + height;
        x_0_pix = 0;

        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

        //построение
        for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {

            y_1 = -y[i];

            y_1_pix = k * (y[i] - y_min) + height;

            x_1_pix = d * (x[i] - x_min) - 1;

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, (float)x_0_pix, (float)y_0_pix, (float)x_1_pix, (float)y_1_pix);

            x_0_pix = x_1_pix; y_0_pix = y_1_pix;

        }
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    }
```

}

**В чем может быть причина ошибки?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто: в момент создания контрола на форме в конструкторе он создаёт его экземпляр, затем пытается нарисовать его, вызывая `pictureBox1_Paint()`. Однако массивы `x` и `y` равны `null` (т.к. код в `Form_Load()` не выполняется в дизайнере форм), что вызывает `NullReferenceException` при обращении к их элементам.

Как вариант решения, могу порекомендовать завести метод `SetData()` (или что-нибудь в этом роде), в котором выполнять передачу данных в контрол, а в `pictureBox1_Paint()` проверять на существование этих данных:

```
// код UserControl'а
private double[] x, y;
private bool dataInitialized = false;

public void SetData(double[] xValues, double[] yValues)
{
    if (xValues.Length != yValues.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException(...);

    // если x == null, то создаст массив
    Array.Resize(ref x, xValues.Length);
    Array.Resize(ref y, yValues.Length);
    Array.Copy(xValues, x, xValues.Length);
    Array.Copy(yValues, y, yValues.Length);

    dataInitialized = true;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataInitialized)
        return;

    // далее остальной код
}
```

Comment: а если просто написать в pictureBox1_Paint

    if (length < 1)// length - длинна массива
    return;

так работает. Какие у такого решения могут быть недостатки?

Comment: 1. доступность переменных `x`, `y` - стоит сделать их private (иначе можно погрузить всё в хаос через присвоение им `null` вне кода элемента управления)
2. создание свойства `Length` только для записи - плохой стиль, т.к. не соответствует традиционному C# коду, да и присвоение Length значения для инициализации - весьма не интуитивно
3. просто более красиво и понятно: по переменной `dataInitialized` легко догадаться, для чего она нужна, а по условию `length < 1` - весьма непросто

Всегда стоит стремиться к более понятному и простому коду.